# Code keeps coming with error

Tags: python

The code keeps coming with an error. I tried fixing the errors but they still don't work. I'll try explain the question again. I have got the code to open the file and read it.

The data is in an excel file.

```
amount (A1)
5.21 (A2)
4.63 (A3)
5.24 (A4)
3.62 (A5)
1.98 (A6)
16.47 (A7)
1.31 (A8)
1.85 (A9)
4.26 (A10)
0.98 (A11)
1.84 (A12)
0.51 (A13) 
15.58 (A14)
2.64 (A15)
4.32 (A16)
0.59 (A17)
0.21 (A18)
5.41 (A19)
0.08 (A20)
4.34 (A21)
```

I tried doing

```
file=open ('3109336a.csv','r')

count = 0

with open('3109336a.csv', 'r') as f:
  values = f.readlines()

  for value in values:
    if float(value) >= 9.79:
      count += 1

print (count)
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXXX\XXXX\studfiles\XXXXX\testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    if float(value) >= 9.79:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'amount, code, quant, val, number, tree\n'
```

The question is:

Count the number of values in field [amount] more than or equal to ( 9.79)

Comment: Oh hi, it's you again, isn't it? At least you have code this time. :-)

Comment: Sorry about earlier I was kind of in a rush.

Comment: Please, do not just destroy the question and answer. When you post here, it is also to help *others* with a similar problem in the future. You posted this under the CC-Wiki license (see bottom right of the page) for that reason.

Comment: Again, do not destroy your question. You can [request to be disassociated from this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki) instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a CSV file, use the right tool to read it. Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('3109336a.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip the first row, it only contains headers.
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        # row is now a *list* of columns.
        # I'll assume the *first* column is your value:
        amount = float(row[0])
        if amount >= 9.79:
            count += 1

    print(count)
```

This can be simplified down to:

```
with open('3109336a.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip the first row, it only contains headers.
    count = sum(1 for row in reader if float(row[0]) >= 9.79)

print(count)
```